# Magento indexer SQL error and category pages display wrong products

Tags: magento, innodb, magento-1.7

My Magento install currently gives me some trouble with the reindex of the Category Products, the search results and the category display.

When I try to reindex everything the Category Products index process gives me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) O)"
```

The search also gives me products that doesn't relate to the search term (an example: when I search for Blackberry the Samsung phones appear together with the Blackberry phones) and I have the same error with the category pages (when I request products from category ID "167" the products from category "167" appear together with the products from category ID "193").

Does anybody know if the SQL error is related to the error with the category pages and if there's a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some invalid data issues. you can do the following.

- backup and truncate "catalog_category_product_index_*" table
- Trying running the Reindexing process again.

Hope it helps..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Magento Database Repair Tool?
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

Comment: Yes, didn't work out. The tool says that there ain't no problems in the database.